# Change y-axis side when plotting factors

Tags: r, graphics, plot, axis-labels

I have the following plot

```
k.factor<-factor(sample(1:5, 100, replace = T))
s.factor<-factor(sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 100, replace = T))
plot(k.factor, s.factor)
```

I would like to remove the left y-axis (A, B, C) and plot this information as a legend. How can I suppress this yaxis? I would also like the probability axis to be displayed as the left y axis (instead of right y axis as it is now)? How can I flip this?

Please base R answers only

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using `ggplot2` you could do it like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(k.factor, s.factor), aes(x = k.factor, fill = s.factor)) + 
   geom_bar(position="fill")
```

Comment: This is a nice solution but I forgot to mention that I was searching for a base R solution. Thanks!

Comment: @ECII You should add that important detail to your original question otherwise other readers will have to read all comments to discover that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `axes=FALSE` in your plotting statement and then manually add the axes using `?axis`:

```
plot(k.factor, s.factor, axes=FALSE)
axis(1)
axis(2)
```

EDIT: In fact, you have to customize the `axis` statement.

```
# create offset and at variables
off <- 0.02
xat <- c(0, cumsum(prop.table(table(k.factor)) + off))
# plot 
plot(k.factor, s.factor)
plot(k.factor, s.factor, axes=FALSE, off=100*off)
axis(1, at = (xat[-length(xat)] + xat[-1] - off)/2, 
     labels = 1:5, tick = FALSE)
axis(2)
```

You can also look at `?spineplot` for more information about the argument `off`.

Comment: this does not work. It just adds the probability axis in side 1 and 2.